# Aksing about pygame background

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

How do you make a white background in pygame? I am having an issue figuring out the correct code to make the background white and where exactly to put it in my code.

Comment: Don't forget to include your code in your question so that we can give better advice.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you make a white background in pygame?

When [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) is called, a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is associated to the display. Everything that is drawn on this *Surface* is visible on the display after the update. [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) the display *Surface* with a white color:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

# [...]

screen.fill("white")

# [...]

pygame.display.flip()
```

> where exactly to put it in my code.

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    
    # handel events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    # update game         

    # clear screen with white color
    screen.fill("white")

    # draw scene
    # [...]
    
    # update diesplay
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```